# sendMessage from a service worker to popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

How can a service worker use sendMessage to communicate with a script running in the popup?

In manifestv3:

- content scripts use chrome.runtime.sendMessage to talk to the service worker.
- the service worker uses chrome.tabs.sendMessage to talk to content scripts.
- content scripts use chrome.runtime.sendMessage to talk to the popup.html's popup.js
- popup.js uses chrome.tabs.sendMessage to talk to content scripts.
- popup.js uses chrome.runtime.sendMessage to talk to the service worker.

In this triangle, the only side missing is between popup.js and the service worker.

How does the service worker message popup.js?

But using chrome.runtime.sendMessage results in "Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."

And using chrome.tabs.sendMessage requires chrome.tabs.query, which doesn't seem to return popup.html at all.

Comment: chrome.runtime.sendMessage is the correct method but it'll work only when the popup is shown so there's no point in using it other than to test if the popup is open. The usual solution is to initiate messaging from the popup and let the background script's onMessage to return the value via sendResponse.